# Git how display all log that had issue references

Tags: git, azure-devops, jira, git-log

Git commit message can reference task id in the Jira or AzureDevOps by using hashtag like: #12345

I want to list **all of the commits** that contain the reference.
Is there any command or tool to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, maybe you can try the following from CLI, take the commit subject and then pipe it to grep to extract the desired info (e.g for commits with #numbers):

`git log --pretty=format:"%s"| grep -E '#[0-9]*'`

Comment: Shorter and simpler: `git log --grep=<pattern>`. Note that this searches the entire commit message, not just the subject line.

Comment: much better, nice